# How to download the best track JTWC data files from 1945 to 2020 using loop?

Tags: bash, shell, wget

I want to download the data files from the URLs using a loop from 1945 to 2020, only one number changes in the URL,
The URLs are given below
https://www.metoc.navy.mil/jtwc/products/best-tracks/1945/1945s-bio/bio1945.zip
https://www.metoc.navy.mil/jtwc/products/best-tracks/1984/1984s-bio/bio1984.zip
https://www.metoc.navy.mil/jtwc/products/best-tracks/2020/2020s-bio/bio2020.zip

I tried the following code, but it throws an error

```
    for i in {1945..2020}
    do
        wget "https://www.metoc.navy.mil/jtwc/products/best-tracks/$i/$is-bio/bio$i.zip"
    done
```

Comment: And the error is...

Comment: HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2022-04-07 13:19:02 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

Comment: Is the data you are trying to access protected with password? A forbidden error seems to imply that you have no permission to access it unless you authenticate yourself with the server.

Comment: No, it is open-source data. You can also check one link from above. It is a hurricane/cyclone track data.

Comment: Hummm... check that you are really trying to open the URL that you think you are opening. You are probably trying to open something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did changed your code slightly

```
for i in {1945..1947}
  do
    echo "https://www.metoc.navy.mil/jtwc/products/best-tracks/$i/$is-bio/bio$i.zip"
  done
```

when run it does output

```
https://www.metoc.navy.mil/jtwc/products/best-tracks/1945/-bio/bio1945.zip
https://www.metoc.navy.mil/jtwc/products/best-tracks/1946/-bio/bio1946.zip
https://www.metoc.navy.mil/jtwc/products/best-tracks/1947/-bio/bio1947.zip
```

Notice that first one is not `https://www.metoc.navy.mil/jtwc/products/best-tracks/1945/1945s-bio/bio1945.zip` as you might expect - 2nd `$i` did not work as intended, as it is followed by `s` it was understand as variable `is` which is not defined. Enclose variable names in `{` `}` to avoid confusion, this code

```
for i in {1945..1947}
  do
    echo "https://www.metoc.navy.mil/jtwc/products/best-tracks/${i}/${i}s-bio/bio${i}.zip"
  done
```

when run does output

```
https://www.metoc.navy.mil/jtwc/products/best-tracks/1945/1945s-bio/bio1945.zip
https://www.metoc.navy.mil/jtwc/products/best-tracks/1946/1946s-bio/bio1946.zip
https://www.metoc.navy.mil/jtwc/products/best-tracks/1947/1947s-bio/bio1947.zip
```

which is compliant with example you gave. Now you might either replace `echo` using `wget` or save output of code with `echo` to file named say `urls.txt` and then harness `-i` option of `wget` as follows

```
wget -i urls.txt
```

Note: for brevity sake I use `1945..1947` in place of `1945..2020`

Answer (score -1):

It directly worked, Thanks @Daweo

```
for i in {1945..2020}
do
    wget "https://www.metoc.navy.mil/jtwc/products/best-tracks/${i}/${i}s-bio/bio${i}.zip"
done
```